# Doctrine 2 Tree Extension: Closure Table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, tree, transitive-closure-table

I'm using Tree - Nestedset behavior extension for Doctrine 2 and Closure Table Strategy. On my web, users can create folders and subfolders and view them. I implemented this by using Closure Table strategy and I render folders with **childrenHierarchy()** method:

```
       $directoryTree = $repository->childrenHierarchy(
            null,  
            true,  
            array(
        'decorate' => false,
        'childSort' => array('field' => 'directory_name', 'dir' => 'asc')
    ));
```

It works fine, but it returns all folders for all users and I don't know how to define **user_id** in this case to render only folders, that belong to login user. Is there any way to do this?

I will glad for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [doc](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#closure-table):

> childrenHierarchy: This useful method allows you to build an array of
>   nodes representing the hierarchy of a tree. **Arguments: node: If you
>   pass a node, the method will return its children. Defaults to "null"
>   (this means it will return ALL nodes)**.

would be something like this:

```
// example, 
$loggedInUserFolder = SOME_METHOD_RETURNS_USER_FOLDER($this->getUser());
$directoryTree = $repository->childrenHierarchy(
            $loggedInUserFolder,  
            true,  
            array(
        'decorate' => false,
        'childSort' => array('field' => 'directory_name', 'dir' => 'asc')
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I added main root directory for each user and it is ok now.